# how to get the hibernate configuration file after decompressing EAR>JAR file through java coding

Tags: java, maven, ear, zip

I have a requirement to get the hibernation configuration file which is inside one JAR file, again this JAR file is inside one EAR file through java coding.

One Ear contains many Jar files and one Jar file contains single hibernate configuration file.

So the structure is something ,

## One EAR -

```
##    --Jar1 ##
 ###     ---Folder Structure, and somewhere in the structure hibernate cfg file resides ###
   ## --Jar2 ##
    ### ---Folder structure, and hibernate cfg file ###
    ##--Jar3 and so on ##
```

What i tried is i have used ZipFileInputStream reader of Java API to decompress EAR file, but i am not getting **real path(Absolute Path)** of the Jar files so that i can extract Jar file and get the hibernate cfg file which is what i wanted from these extraction hierarchy.

I am able to do decompress sample EAR which directly contains hibernate cfg file using ZipFileInputStream reader of java API using java coding. but my requirement is EAR contains JAR and this JAR contains configuration file for which i am looking for. This all i am doing through java programming

Below is the code snippet for EAR containing .cfg.xml file.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/ContactManager.ear"); 
      ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis)); 
      ZipEntry entry = null; String pathName;
      String fileName; 
      while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) { pathName = entry.getName(); 
      if(pathName.endsWith(".cfg.xml")){ System.out.println("path name "+pathName);
```

Kindly advice me the best possible ways to achieve this task. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try [TrueZip](https://truezip.java.net/) or just extract ZIP file contents to temporary directory and try to read it as separate ZIP file.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. but i am using java to get it done through coding

Comment: @Sandy so please show that you've already done (code) and I'll try to help you.

Comment: FileInputStream fis = new
FileInputStream("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/ContactManager.ear");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

    ZipEntry entry = null;
    String pathName;
    String fileName;

    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    pathName = entry.getName();


    if(pathName.endsWith(".cfg.xml")){
        System.out.println("path name "+pathName);

Comment: @Sandy your code is truncated here. Can you update original post?

Comment: i have updated original question with simple working code.